# :input selector returning button but :not([type=button]) doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm combining selectors in order to select only specific inputs in my html :

```
$('.content_container :input[type=radio]:checked, .content_container :input:not([type=radio])')
```

The problem there is that it also returns the `<button type='button'>`

I have tried adding the following:

```
.content_container :input:not([type=button])
.content_container :button:not([type=button])
```

To my selector, but it still returns the button. How can I arrange this ?

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't aware of that. Thanks. I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine both types in a single `:not()`.

```
.content_container :input:not([type=radio],[type=button])
```

Otherwise, the selector with `:not([type=radio])` returns all the other types of inputs, including buttons, and the selector with `:not([type=button])` returns all the other inputs, including radios, so when you combine them you get both radios and buttons, instead of excluding both.